# Mostrar ubicación actual maps tras pulsar botón

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

llevo unos días trabajando con la API de maps y estoy teniendo problemas.

La cosa es que quiero que al abrir la página se muestre el mapa con un marcador en una posición determinada. Y que posteriormente, si quieres saber tu ubicación, pulses un botón y que se añada un marcador en el mapa en ella.

La primera parte lo consigo, pero lo que no consigo es mostrar mi ubicación pulsando el botón. Yo imagino que no capturo bien el click, o tengo su función mal posicionada en mi código.

¿Podeis ayudarme? ¡Gracias!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function localizacion(posicion) {

    var latitudReal = null;
    var longitudReal = null;

    $('#UbicacionPersonal').click(function() {
      latitudReal = posicion.coords.latitude;
      longitudReal = posicion.coords.longitude;
    });

    var latitud = 39.579745;
    var longitud = 2.654018;

    //Generamos el mapa que muestre y cual será el punto central
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('Mapa'), {
      center: {
        lat: latitud,
        lng: longitud
      },
      zoom: 14
    });

    //Generamos el marcadores para señalar una posición
    var markerMiPosicion = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: latitud,
        lng: longitud
      },
      title: "Ubicación estudiante"
    });
    var markerPosicionReal = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: latitudReal,
        lng: longitudReal
      },
      title: "Mi actual ubicación"
    });

    // Mostramos los marcadores en el mapa.
    markerMiPosicion.setMap(map);
    markerPosicionReal.setMap(map);

  }

  // En caso de no poder geolocalizar hay que tener un mensaje de error (o acción)
  function error() {
    alert('No se puede obtener tu ubicación actual')
    // un error a valorar es que el usuario no permite la geoloc, code:1
  }


  // Ahora empleamos todo lo declarado anteriormente.
  // Comprobamos si el navegador soporta la geolocalización
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    //Caso SI soporta geolocalización. Ejecuto la API y llamo a mis funciones.
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(localizacion, error);
  } else {
    //Caso NO soporta geolocalización
    alert('Navegador NO soporta geolocalización');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Mapa"></div>

<input type="button" id="UbicacionPersonal" value="Mi ubicación">
```

¡Salud!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respecto a tu código, estás declarando las variables `latitudReal` y `longitudReal` como nulas:

```
var latitudReal = null;
var longitudReal = null;
```

Sólo le asignas valor si acaso el usuario pincha en el botón `#UbicacionPersonal`.

```
$('#UbicacionPersonal').click(function() {
  latitudReal = posicion.coords.latitude;
  longitudReal = posicion.coords.longitude;
});
```

Sin embargo, aunque el usuario no ha presionado el botón, tu código sigue adelante e intenta dibujar el marker con la ubicación del usuario:

```
var markerPosicionReal = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {
    lat: latitudReal,
    lng: longitudReal
  },
  title: "Mi actual ubicación"
});

// Mostramos los marcadores en el mapa.
markerMiPosicion.setMap(map);
markerPosicionReal.setMap(map);
```

Cuando instancias `markerPosicionReal` las variables `latitudReal` y `longitudReal` siguen siendo nulas (el usuario no ha presionado el botón) y google maps no puede dibujar un marker con coordenadas nulas.

Lo correcto sería dibujar ese marcador dentro del listener del click del botón:

```
$('#UbicacionPersonal').click(function () {
    latitudReal = posicion.coords.latitude;
    longitudReal = posicion.coords.longitude;
    var markerPosicionReal = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: latitudReal,
          lng: longitudReal
        },
        title: "Mi actual ubicación"
    });
    markerPosicionReal.setMap(map);
    // Si quieres centrar el mapa en el nuevo marker:
    map.setCenter(markerPosicionReal.getPosition());
});
```

Y este listener debes declararlo **despues de instanciar el mapa** porque antes de eso `map` es `undefined`.

---

Dicho lo anterior, hay dos observaciones:

**Primero**, no vas a poder correr este código en los snippets de stackoverflow porque esos scripts corren en un sandbox en donde el uso de geolocation está explícitamente deshabilitado (el iframe no tiene `allow-same-origin` en su atributo `sandbox`):

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    console.log(position);
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
} else {
  //Caso NO soporta geolocalización
  alert('Navegador NO soporta geolocalización');
}
```

**Segundo**, vas a necesitar correr tu código en un sitio con `https`, porque de lo contrario navegadores como Chrome no te permitirán usar el api `geolocation`.

Te dejo un ejemplo que sí funciona:

https://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/6dur3dr8/